# Asset Pipeline not serving assets, but no errors. Does this config look correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm a RoR newbie (but a seasoned developer) and I've been enjoying it... but I've hit a brick wall with the Asset Pipeline!  I have a legacy application that I'm modifying to use the asset pipeline.  I have read article after article on SO and other sites, but I just cannot get this working.  Here are the details:

**Ruby Version** : 2.0.0-p353

**Rails Version** : 3.1.12

Contents of directory **app/assets/javascripts**:

```
application.js          
bootstrap.js            
event_calendar.js       
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js   
jquery-ui.js            
jquery.js
jquery.prettyPhoto.js
jrails.js
mce_editor.js
rails.js
/tiny_mce
```

Contents of file **application.js**:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require event_calendar
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.prettyPhoto
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
//= require jrails
//= require mce_editor
//= require rails
//= require_tree ./tiny_mce
```

Contents of directory **app/assets/stylesheets**:

```
application.css         
/blueprint          
bootstrap-responsive.css    
bootstrap.css           
common.css          
contributed.css         
event_calendar.css      
jquery-custom.css
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css
marketing.css
prettyPhoto.css
registration.css
sysadministration.css
template.css
/ui-darkness
```

Contents of file **application.css**:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootstrap-responsive
*= require common
*= require contributed
*= require event_calendar
*= require jquery-custom
*= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
*= require marketing
*= require prettyPhoto
*= require registration
*= require sysadministration
*= require template
*= require_tree ./blueprint
*= require_tree ./ui-darkness
*/
```

Setting in **config/application.rb**:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Helpers in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Settings in **config/environments/development.rb**:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.debug = true
```

Contents of folder **/public/assets**:

```
(empty)
```

When I browse to `localhost:3000/assets/application.js`, I simply get the contents of the application.js file returned.   Likewise for application.css.  However there is a conspicuous trailing semicolon from application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require event_calendar
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.prettyPhoto
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
//= require jrails
//= require mce_editor
//= require rails
//= require_tree ./tiny_mce
;
```

I have tried chasing down that trailing semicolon with no luck. I've changed the order of the require statements, thinking I might be able to narrow down any syntax errors in the .js code, but that effort was unsuccessful.

When my pages are rendered, it is without any styling or js (as expected since the asset pipeline is not working).

I have also tried using the `require_tree .` directives in application.css and application.js rather than explicitly listing each file, but that didn't work either.

Finally, there are no errors showing up in my server console. It appears that Rails thinks the assets are being served correctly:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-02 15:31:02 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-02 15:31:02 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

Based on the information I've provided, are there any glaring omissions to my configuration?  Anyone have some suggestions to get this working??

Thanks!

Comment: you should load jquery js first before other js, by the way do you see  others js loaded on browser ?

Comment: Definitely nothing in your files before the directives (including invisible characters)? PS: if you're starting a new project I'd recommend something newer than rails 3.1 (which doesn't receive updates any more)

Comment: Also, In development rails should serve each file required in application.js separately

Comment: `require_tree` is not order specific.  Does the order in which you require tiny_mce js files matter?  That could be causing your mysterious semicolon

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  In response to comments: I changed the loading order as suggested, and no other js in the browser. There are no invisible characters in the files, I surely would *not* use Rails 3.1 for a new application :)  Re tiny_mce, I eliminated it and mce_editor but the semicolon is still present (even when just one 'require' line in application.js, the semicolon appears).   The application I'm working on was 3.0 and I upgraded it.  Now I'm wondering if I should go to 3.2 and see if that fixes this asset pipeline issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to upgrade to Rails 3.2.18, and that resolved this issue (I followed RailsGuides #318 "Upgrading to Rails 3.2").  Now my js and css is being delivered to the browser:

[image: application.js]

[image: application.css]

And the server console shows assets being delivered individually (dev mode):

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery-custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jquery-custom.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/contributed.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /contributed.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

[deleted for brevity]

Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jquery.prettyPhoto.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/event_calendar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /event_calendar.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/mce_editor.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /mce_editor.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/jrails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /jrails.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/rails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /rails.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 06:07:20 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```